# Inference of a model not working properly only giving one instance

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I have an inference script that tells about the type of clothing, it works perfectly fine:

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from PIL import Image
import torch.nn as nn

MODEL_PATH = "/content/deepfashion-dataset/models/stage-1_resnet34.pkl"
DATA_PATH = "/content/deepfashion-dataset/"
CLASSES_PATH = "/content/deepfashion-dataset/clothes_categories/classes.txt"

class ClassificationModel():
    
    def __init__(self):
        return
        
    def load(self, model_path, labels_path,  eval=False):
        self.model = torch.load(model_path)
        self.model = nn.Sequential(self.model)
        
        self.labels = open(labels_path, 'r').read().splitlines()
        
        if eval:
            print(model.eval())
        return
    
    def predict(self, image_path):
        
        device = torch.device("cpu")
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        
        test_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224),
                                      transforms.ToTensor(),
                                      transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                                           [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
                                     ])
        
        image_tensor = test_transforms(img).float()
        image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)
        inp = Variable(image_tensor)
        inp = inp.to(device)
        output = self.model(inp)
        index = output.data.cpu().numpy().argmax()
        return self.labels[index]

learner = ClassificationModel()
learner.load(MODEL_PATH, CLASSES_PATH)
learner.predict(DATA_PATH+"img-lk/IMG_20210530_152109_062.jpg")
```

I get the result : like blouse, skirt, pants etc. The labels file is like this:

```
Anorak
Blazer
Blouse
Bomber
Button-Down
Caftan
Capris
Cardigan
Chinos
Coat
```

Now I have another model trained on the same dataset that tells about the attributes and material of the clothing, I have the same inference script above, obviously changing the model path and the classes path with attribute classes file, that is structured like this:

```
abstract-print
animal
baroque
basic
beach
bird-print
boho
botanical-print
camouflage
cargo
chic
chiffon
```

The thing is that it works for the clothing type but for clothing attributes it only gives me one attribute. While when I trained the model it gave me all the attributes that were likely:

[image]

Now with the above script when I do inference it just gives me: Leather (just one attribute). I need to have it all, like in the image shared. I do have the model in pkl and pth both.

predict attribute function that worked when i used it after training:

```
def predict_attribute(model, path, display_img=True):
    predicted = model.predict(path)
    if display_img:
        size = 244,244
        img=Image.open(path)
        img.thumbnail(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
        display(img)
    return predicted[0]
```

Comment: Can we have a look at your `predict_attribute` function, it's very likely that's it is not handling the model's output the same way as you are doing it in `predict` (*i.e.* with the `argmax`)?

Comment: @Ivan i have edited the code and added that, i can share the colab notebook link if needed too.